# How can I convert this cascading dropdown select from Class to functional hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, cascadingdropdown

I have this cascading select dropdown of country, state and LGA. I will like to convert it to functional component in React. I have tried but with no success. When a user select a country

The constructor part is as below. I think that will work for useState or something like that. See the part below:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            countries : [],
            states : [],
            lgas : [],
            selectedCountry : '--Choose Country--',
            selectedState : '--Choose State--'
        };
        this.changeCountry = this.changeCountry.bind(this);
        this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    }
```

The componentDidMount have the data from Country, State and LGA. But I think it will be better off in a separate file. But I don't know how to map it to the main file. See the sample data below.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            countries : [
                { name: 'Nigeria', value: 'nigeria', 
                states: [ {name: 'Abia', value: 'abia', 
                lgas: [
                        {name: "Aba", value: 'aba'},
                        {name: "Oru", value: 'oru'},

        ]}, {name: 'Adamawa', value: 'adamawa', 
                lgas: [
                        {name: 'Demsa', value: 'demsa'},
                        {name: 'Fufure', value: 'fufure'},
        ]}, 
    },  
            ]
        });
    }
```

Then the changeValue functions for Country and States. How do I convert it to React functional Hooks? See the sample below.

```
changeCountry(event) {
        this.setState({selectedCountry: event.target.value});
        this.setState({states : this.state.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === event.target.value).states});
    }

    changeState(event) {
        this.setState({selectedState: event.target.value});
        const stats = this.state.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === this.state.selectedCountry).states;
        this.setState({lgas : stats.find(stats => stats.name === event.target.value).lgas});
    }
```

**EDITED**
I tried to wire the code submitted by Ali Muhammad to the form area but it's not working out.  I am including it below. Please help me look into it.

```
<div id="container">
                <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>
                <div>
                    <Label>Country</Label>
                    <Select placeholder="Country" value={state.selectedCountry} onChange={changeCountry}>
                        <option>--Choose Country--</option>
                        {state.countries.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Label>State</Label>
                    <Select placeholder="State" value={state.selectedState} onChange={changeState}>
                        <option>--Choose State--</option>
                        {state.states.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Label>LGA</Label>
                    <Select placeholder="LGA" value={state.selectedLga}>
                        <option>--Choose LGA--</option>
                        {state.lgas.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The code is hosted on [CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-curran-q8o5s) The main file is the LocationDropdown.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
            countries : [],
            states : [],
            lgas : [],
            selectedCountry : '--Choose Country--',
            selectedState : '--Choose State--'
        });
```

Move your `componentDidMount` code in `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            countries : [
                { name: 'Nigeria', value: 'nigeria', 
                states: [ {name: 'Abia', value: 'abia', 
                lgas: [
                        {name: "Aba", value: 'aba'},
                        {name: "Oru", value: 'oru'},

        ]}, {name: 'Adamawa', value: 'adamawa', 
                lgas: [
                        {name: 'Demsa', value: 'demsa'},
                        {name: 'Fufure', value: 'fufure'},
        ]}, 
    },  
            ]
   }));
}, [])
```

and then your handlers:

```js
function changeCountry(event) {
  setState(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     selectedCountry: event.target.value,
     states : prevState.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === event.target.value).states
  }));
}

function changeState(event) {
   setState(prevState => {
     const stats = prevState.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === prevState.selectedCountry).states;
     return {
       ...prevState,
       selectedState: event.target.value,
       lgas : stats.find(sts => sts.name === event.target.value).lgas
     }
   )); 
}
```

**But you should use multiple states or `useReducer` hook to manage your states, I just wanted to show you how you can convert your component.**